# Write the first line text of ComboBox C#

Tags: c#

I got one ComboBox. If i select the first line (or any other) and click on button, it will say `MessageBox.Show("You have been selected the");` and it will write in the textbox what you have been selected from the combobox, like Test1, Test2, etc. So it will say `MessageBox.Show("You have been selected the Test1");. I don't know how i can get the value from Items > (Collection) (maybe). Any ideas so i can do that? I already tried`MessageBox.Show("You have been selected the " + ComboBox1.Items); but it gives me all of the lines in the Collections.

Comment: Use the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Please specify the technology you use: Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: @KlausGütter Winforms

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the appropriate tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

We have to make some assumptions here since you don't have any appropriate tags, but the probable solution is to replace your `ComboBox1.Items` with `ComboBox1.SelectedItem`, for a line like this:

`MessageBox.Show("You have been selected the "+ ComboBox1.SelectedItem);`

Comment: `SelectedText` <> `SelectedItem`